# Connect Java application 64bit to ODBC driver 32bits

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, erp, jdbc-odbc

I am building a Java desktop application that should connect to Sage ERP via ODBC driver.
However, I have a 64bit windows7 OS and the ODBC driver is 32bit. The thing that had generated the followingv exception:

[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Just for info, I am configuring the DSN via C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.

After googling around my query, I think a solution would be to enforce the java application to run in 32 bit JVM mode.
 Can anyone help to get through this please

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative. You can use a JDBC-ODBC Bridge where the bridge part is not only a bridge between JDBC and ODBC but a bridge between 64 bit and 32 bit systems. The one [here](http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/jdbc_odbc_bridge/index.html) does that by separating the JDBC driver from a 32 bit server via a socket.

Comment: I actually did resolve this by simply downloading a 32bits JVM and configuring eclipse to run on it. This way my Java application will automaticaly run via the 32bits ODBC defines DSN.

Answer (score -1):

to run your code just simply type follwing command on cmd
" c:\progra~2\java\jdk1.7.0\bin"
and then compile and run ur program....
follow the command as it is do not change a single character except the version of jdk

Comment: This answer probably has NO relation to the question asked by the OP. Please revisit this.